# Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) when trying a subquery

Tags: sql

I have created two table **person** with column *id, name, mobile* and another is **transaction** table with *id, quantity, rate, total,  pay, due*, one person can have multiple entry in transaction table.
Now, I want to see the total quantity, total payment and total due against each name in person table.
I don't know much about sql, that's why I try for total quantity first but it give me error: "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

My sql is:

```
 select id,name from person where(id) in 

(select id, sum(quantity) from transaction group by id);
```

What can i do for, showing all field like: total quantity, total pay, total due.

Comment: could you please provide some sample data

Comment: @Fahmi No need, here.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join`

```
select id,name,total
from person p join
(select id, sum(quantity) as total from transaction group by id) as t on p.id=t.id
```

OR

```
select p.id,name,sum(quantity) as total from person p join transaction t 
on p.id=t.id
group by p.id, name
```

Comment: It should be `group by p.id, name`

Comment: I'd stick to the subquery version. GROUP BY combined with JOIN can give unexpected results, depending on what type of relatation it is.

Comment: @jarlh, agreed with you as OP didn't provide sample data I was not sure, so answered both options :)